# Is there an equivalent option similar to makefile '-j' for visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, makefile

In make build systems we can use -j  N: number of parallel jobs.
Is there a similar option for visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version.  If you are using VS2005 or VS2008 then in Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run there is an option to specify the number of parallel project builds.  However, this is a very coarse-grained approach.  The structure of your projects will affect whether this gives you any speed up at all.  If you are using VS2010 then I *believe* that it has better support for parallel building, but someone else will have to clarify that.

Other (commercial) options are [MPCL](http://www.todobits.es/mpcl.html) which is cheap and may give you a good boost, or [Incredibuild](http://www.xoreax.com/) which is more of a corporate solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. At least not anything as strong as make -j.
You can either build projects in parallel or compile C files in parallel using /MP.
btw, Incredibuild only distribute these on different machines, but they are too limited to either /MP option or several projects in parallel. They cannot build several targets in parallel.

See also: [Speed up C++ build times by means of parallel compilation](http://blog.kutny.net/2012/01/27/speed-up-c-build-times-by-means-of-parallel-compilation/)